# Solving Inequalities.....

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $ a\leq b$ and $ a < c $ , what relationship can we obtain between $b$ and $c$.

Comment: What have you tried? What's the context of this question?

Answer (score 3):

We can't ascertain any particular relationship. Try various combinations of $a,b,c$ to see why:

- $a = 0, b = 1, c = 2$: both inequalities true, $b < c$
- $a = 0, b = 5, c = 2$: both inequalities true, $b > c$
- $a = 0, b = 3, c = 3$: both inequalities true, $b = c$